# Image link expands to fill max-width, but ignores max-height

Tags: html, css, height, width, erb

I have an image that is a link. I assigned it a class and assigned that class a max-width and max-height. However, the image expands to the max-width and disregards the max-height.

**erb:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@user.image, class:"avatar"), "#" %>
```

**css:**

```
.avatar {max-width: 50px; max-height: 40px; position: relative; float: left;}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it's doing this??

### **EDIT**

Okay now I'm really confused...the problem persisted for like two hours but literally right after I posted this question, it randomly started working without me changing any code....maybe it was being cached somehow? Anyway, problem solved I guess..

Comment: have you tried `max-height: 40px !important;`. yeah most probably a caching issue...

Comment: @MazeRunner That was really really weird, the problem persisted for like 2 hours but started working right after I posted this question, even though I didn't change any code afterwards.